# Include the pk or models fields when creating the object in POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have my Order model which has a FK to Item model. I customized the Order create method to create the item which is passed in from the POST request. I want to customize it to allow the POST request to pass the Item pk instead of the name. so if the pk exists, I just use it and no need to create a new item.

However, when I look at the `validated_data` values in the create(), the id field doesn't exist.

```
class Item(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=False)

class Order(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User,blank=True)
        item = models.OneToOneField(Item,blank=True)
```

I want the POST body to be

```
{  
     "name":"iPhone"
}
```

or

```
{  
     "id":15
}
```

Comment: Would you share you code? How are you posting the data?

Comment: @kia this is basiclly my code. I'm using nested routers so /users/<id>/orders is my post URL and the body is what I have above.

Comment: What's your view code ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement this kind of behavior myself, and didn't find a satisfying way in terms of quality. I think it's error prone to create a new object without having the user confirming it, because the user could type in "iphone" or "iPhon" instead of "iPhone" for example, and it could create a duplicate item for the iphone.

Instead, I recommend to have two form fields:

- a select field for the item name,
- a text input to create an item that's not in the list.

Then, it's easy to [handle in the form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Or, with autocompletion:

- user types in an Item name in an autocompletion field,
- if it doesn't find anything, the autocomplete box proposes to `create the "iPhon" Item`,
- then the user can realize they have a typo,
- or click to `create the "iPhone" item` in which case it's easy to trigger an ajax request on a dedicated view which would respond with the new pk, to set in the form field
- the form view can behave normally, no need to add confusing code.

This is how the example "creating choices on the fly" is demonstrated in django-autocomplete-light.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/).

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from .models import Order, Item
from django.shortcuts import render


class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    item_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.none(), required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Item.objects.all()

    def clean_item(self):
        item_name = self.cleaned_data['item_name']
        item = self.cleaned_data['item']
        if item:
            return item
        if not item_name:
            raise ValidationError('New item name or existing one is required.')
        return Item.objects.create(name=item_name)


@login_required
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': OrderForm()})

    user = request.user
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = Order.objects.create(user=user, item=form.cleaned_data['item'])
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': OrderForm(), 'order': order, 'success': True})
    else:
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': OrderForm(), 'error': True})
```

Comment: I checked the validation, didn't I?

Comment: True, my bad, but I find it a bit of a shame to not encapsulate this logic in the form class, making it reusable, and allowing it to change without having to change the view code. Also, I don't see where in this code is the switch allowing the user to post "name" instead of "pk" which I thought was the point of this question.

Comment: Are you sure it works to pass a manager to queryset ? By "encapsulate this logic in the form class" i meant using `ModelForm.save()`.